# Javascript: http request, how to iterate JSON object response

Tags: javascript, json, httprequest, httpresponse

I am querying a graphQL endpoint through http request and I am getting a successful response with the data that I need to collect, however, I can't seem to navigate through the data to pull the fields I require.

```
 const query = JSON.stringify({query:
               '{' +
               '   all_insight_article('+
               '     locale: "en-gb"'+
               '     where: {business_unit: {business_unit: {title: "Some Brand"}, MATCH: ALL}, audience: {MATCH: ALL, audiences: {title: "Management"}}publish_date_gt: "2023-02-01"}'+
               '   ) {items {'+
               '     audienceConnection {'+
               '         edges {'+
               '           node {... on Audiences {title system {uid}}}}}'+
               '       system {'+
               '         uid'+
               '         publish_details {time}'+
               '         updated_at}'+
               '         absolute_url'+
               '         title'+
               '         subtitle'+
               '         main_image'+
               '         topicsConnection {'+
               '         edges {'+
               '           node {'+
               '             ... on Topics {'+
               '               title'+
               '               display_name'+
               '               system {uid}}}}}}total}}'
        });

var req = new HttpClientRequest("https://eu-graphql.contentstack.com/stacks/bltcxxx?environment=xxx&access_token=xxx")
req.header["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
req.method = "POST"
req.body = query
req.execute()
var response = req.response;
var posts = JSON.parse(response.body);
var articleList_json = [];

var i
for ( i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  articleList_json.push({
    "title": posts[i].title,
  });
}

logInfo(articleList_json);
```

The error I get is `posts is undefined.`

Note: `HttpClientRequest` is a class for my application, but is pretty much a standard http request https://experienceleague.adobe.com/developer/campaign-api/api/c-HttpClientRequest.html

**2nd update**

I tried the following but still does not work

```
var response = req.response;  
var posts = JSON.stringify(response.body);
var articleList_json = [];

var i
for ( i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  var graphQLJSON = JSON.parse(posts[i]);
  articleList_json.push({
    "title": graphQLJSON.data.title,
  });
}

logInfo(articleList_json);
```

Comment: FYI: that monstrosity of a string can be simplified with a template literal (string with backticks)

Comment: Also, what exactly do you want to do? Do you need to get certain fields, or iterate over many fields? If you need to iterate, then over which fields?

Comment: Which fields, or what is the criteria?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with the new structure and the mappings, I am having trouble even pulling the simple title.

Comment: I tried `posts[i].data.all_insight_article.items.title` to pull the title but nothing, still returning undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse()` takes a ***string*** in json structure and parses it:

> The JSON.parse() static method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the resulting object before it is returned.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

JSON string example:

```js
const json = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

`HttpClientRequest` returns a `HttpClientResponse` object which you must first convert to a string before parsing it (on the condition that the returned string is in valid json structure):

```js
var content = response.body.toString(response.codePage);
var posts = JSON.parse(content);
```

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/developer/campaign-api/api/p-HttpClientResponse-body.html

Full documentation example:

```js
var http = new HttpClientRequest("http://www.google.com/")
http.execute()
var response = http.response
if( response.code != 200 )
  throw "HTTP request failed with " + response.message
var content = response.body.toString(response.codePage)
```

Comment: How would I pull the title from the JSON? `posts[i].data.all_insight_article.items.title` doesnt seem to work

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, as I'm not entirely familiar with the API and I can't see the data returned as well. That could be a separate question that you ask with the appropriate info. In response to this particular question, though, the problem would be the way you are handling the response as described in my answer. Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks, the response returned example is here https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/y23e94b41 I will keep testing

Comment: are you sure that the array is in `posts` rather than `all_insight_article.items`? i.e. should you be accessing it as `all_insight_article.items[i]` instead of `posts[i]`?

Comment: perhaps console.log the `posts` object and see if it's an array. If it isn't then `posts[i]` is not gonna work. console.log `posts.data.all_insight_article.items[i]` and observe that.. you might be looking for `posts.data.all_insight_article.items[i].title`

Comment: In fact, looking at the example response, it looks like `title` is in fact in `posts.data.all_insight_article.items[0].title` - "Six key differences between private equity and public market investing"

Comment: `var response = JSON.stringify(req.response);
var posts = JSON.parse(response.body);
var articleList_json = [];
var i;

for ( i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  articleList_json.push({
    "title": posts.data.all_insight_article.items[i].title,
  });
}`

Comment: I get `22/02/2023 03:30:38 js JST-310000 Error while compiling script 'WKF12/js' line 46: JSON.parse.` something wrong with the parse, am I not applying that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work finally

```
var response = req.response;
var jsonData = JSON.parse(response.body)

    var articleList_json = [];
    var i;
    
    for (i = 0; (i < 15 && i < jsonData.data.all_insight_article.items.length); i++) {
      articleList_json.push({
        "title": jsonData.data.all_insight_article.items[i].title.toString()
      });
    }
    logInfo("Count "+i);
    
    logInfo(JSON.stringify(articleList_json));
```

console log of array of objects

```
[
  {
    "title": "Six key differences between private equity and public market investing"
  },
  {
    "title": "Securing the supply of rare earth metals is central to our energy transition"
  },
  {
    "title": "Test article for charts"
  },
  {
    "title": "Central banks hike rates again - but for how much longer?"
  }
]
```